# Finish Date not correct

Tags: ms-project, planning, scheduling, ms-project-2013, reporting

I have one task that starts on 8/1/22 and ends on 1/23/23, but the duration is 2.5 days. The end date isn't calculating correctly.

I have theses resources assigned to the task, total 27.2 baseline work hours...

EE... 20h
ME... .4h
TE-E... 1.2h
MA... 5.6h

The task is auto calculated and only has one predecessor which is the task right above it.

How do I get the finish date corrected?

Comment: Can you add an screenshot of the task with the task form open and the Gantt chart visible? That will make it much easier for all of us to see what might be going on.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Resource Usage view to see when each resource is scheduled to work on that task. Perhaps one of them isn't scheduled until Jan 2023. If that's the case, look at that resource's calendar.

Alternatively, remove one resource at a time to see which one is driving the finish date out.

Comment: Thanks that helped!